# Suppress line numbering for empty lines in listings package

Tags: listings, line-numbering

The `listings` package quite nicely formats my pseudo code listings. Is there a way that one can specify that line numbering should be suppressed for empty lines?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `numberblanklines=false`; a little example:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{numbers=left,numberblanklines=false}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
First line.

Second line.
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The above approach will not number blank lines, but will take them into account for increasing the counter controlling the line numbering; you can define a command to decrease the counter manually; something like this:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{numbers=left,numberblanklines=false,escapeinside=||}
\newcommand*\DNumber{\addtocounter{lstnumber}{-1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
First line.|\DNumber|

Second line.|\DNumber|

Third line.
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Marco Daniel suggested the following automated way of preventing blank lines from increasing the counter, by defining a new key `countblanklines` and using the macro `\lst@AddToHook{<hook>}`:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{numbers=left,numberblanklines=false}

\makeatletter
\lst@Key{countblanklines}{true}[t]%
    {\lstKV@SetIf{#1}\lst@ifcountblanklines}

\lst@AddToHook{OnEmptyLine}{%
    \lst@ifnumberblanklines\else%
       \lst@ifcountblanklines\else%
         \advance\c@lstnumber-\@ne\relax%
       \fi%
    \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
First line.

Second line.

Third.
\end{lstlisting}


\begin{lstlisting}[countblanklines=false]
First line.

Second line.

Third.
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I understand that this suppresses the printing of the line numbers howver still increases the line counter. Is there a way to specify that an empty line does not increase the line counter?

Comment: @user9131: see my updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

You could add the line decrement routine suggested by @Gonzalo using a hook into `OnEmptyLines`. This is provided by the macro `\lst@AddToHook{<hook>}`. The convenience, of course, is that one is not required to escape out of the listing in order to decrease the counter. However, this then generalizes the approach for all `OnEmptyLines`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
\makeatletter
\lst@AddToHook{OnEmptyLine}{\addtocounter{lstnumber}{-1}}% Remove line number increment from listings
\makeatother
\lstset{numbers=left,numberblanklines=false}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
First line.

Second line.

Third line.
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}​
```

Comment: Yes, this is the way to go.