# Suppress line numbering for specific lines in listings package

Tags: listings, line-numbering

I would like to suppress the line numbering for specific lines in `listings` package by identifying the specific lines using some kind of command.

Comment: Please accept answers. In your previous question there are 2 answers without any response: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33999/suppress-line-numbering-for-empty-lines-in-listings-package

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It isn't such simple as it sounds. You have to hook every line. Here a small solution which needs more testing:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{numbers=left,numberblanklines=false,escapeinside=||}
\let\origthelstnumber\thelstnumber
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\Suppressnumber{%
  \lst@AddToHook{OnNewLine}{%
    \let\thelstnumber\relax%
     \advance\c@lstnumber-\@ne\relax%
    }%
}

\newcommand*\Reactivatenumber{%
  \lst@AddToHook{OnNewLine}{%
   \let\thelstnumber\origthelstnumber%
   \advance\c@lstnumber\@ne\relax}%
}


\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
First line.
Second line.|\Suppressnumber|
Third line.
Next line.|\Reactivatenumber|
Next Line
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Next time please provide an example. I took this one from you previous question.

Comment: Sorry for not providing an example; I felt my question was simple. Anyhow, thank you very much for the answer. I tried it and got the following result:

Comment: I suppose that you do not need the `\global` and why do you have all the `\relax` after the `let` statement?

Comment: @Herbert: The `\relax` is obsolete. I know this. I don't know why I haven't changed it. -- I tested without global and it works.

Comment: Everything worked, except the line numbers were not suppressed, but the line number was just repeated so I saw 1 xxx 2 xxx 2 xxx 3 xxx.

Comment: @user9131: Marco's example works fine, showing that there's no line number printed after `|\Suppressnumber|`. What did you do differently? Did you receive any warnings in your `.log`? Perhaps you have an older version of [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) - currently at `1.4`. To see whether this is the case, add `\listfiles` before `\documentclass` and check your `.log` file after `*File List*`.

Comment: Shame on me; I must have done something wrong. It works. Thank you all for your help. Now the listing looks exactly as I like it. Just perfect.