# Skip line numbers and resume from specific number

Tags: listings, line-numbering

I'm a total latex noob, I would like to accomplish something similar to what has been asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34094/suppress-line-numbering-for-specific-lines-in-listings-package), but rather than resuming numbering from where it was left off, I'd like to pass the new line number as argument to the `\Reactivatenumber` command. Sort of like this:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{numbers=left,numberblanklines=false,escapeinside=||}
\let\origthelstnumber\thelstnumber
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\Suppressnumber{%
  \lst@AddToHook{OnNewLine}{%
    \let\thelstnumber\relax%
     \advance\c@lstnumber-\@ne\relax%
    }%
}

\newcommand*\Reactivatenumber{%
  \lst@AddToHook{OnNewLine}{%
   \let\thelstnumber\origthelstnumber%
   \advance\c@lstnumber\@ne\relax}%
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
var myFunc = function() {|\Suppressnumber|
    //my function does many great things
    //and it's only 10 lines long!|\Reactivatenumber{12}|
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

To produce something like this (pardon formatting):

```
 1 | var myFunc = function() {
   |    //my function does many great things
   |    //and it's only 10 lines long!
12 | }
```

What would be the right way to define the `\Reactivatenumber` command? Cheers.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Alright, I apologize for I thought citing a similar question and then just writing the part of code that should differ would suffice; also, please be advised that the complete code, as it looks now, may not compile (though I have not tried), since I wrote `|\Reactivatenumber{12}|` which is my _desiderata_, how I'd like to change the command in order to do what I'd like it to. Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the `lstnumber` counter to one less than the next line number in `Reactivatenumber`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{numbers=left,numberblanklines=false,escapeinside=||}
\let\origthelstnumber\thelstnumber
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\Suppressnumber{%
  \lst@AddToHook{OnNewLine}{%
    \let\thelstnumber\relax%
     \advance\c@lstnumber-\@ne\relax%
    }%
}

\newcommand*\Reactivatenumber[1]{%
  \lst@AddToHook{OnNewLine}{%
   \let\thelstnumber\origthelstnumber%
   \setcounter{lstnumber}{\numexpr#1-1\relax}%
   %\advance\c@lstnumber\@ne\relax%
  }%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
var myFunc = function() {|\Suppressnumber|
    //my function does many great things
    //and it's only 10 lines long!|\Reactivatenumber{12}|
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wonderful, exactly what I needed. Cheers.

Comment: The line number don't count up after Reactivatenumber (they just continue as 12, 12, 12, 12,...). Solution here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/264373/39635