# Skipping line numbers in lstlisting

Tags: listings, line-numbering

Referring to [Skip line numbers and resume from specific number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215697/skip-line-numbers-and-resume-from-specific-number) I tried to skip several line numbers in my listings and continue with a specific number. But in my case there is a really bad side effect: each line after `\Reactivatenumber{...}` has the same number. Also new listings have the number defined in the previous `\Reactivatenumber{...}`

My Example:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{numbers=left,numberblanklines=false,escapeinside=||}
\let\origthelstnumber\thelstnumber
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\Suppressnumber{%
  \lst@AddToHook{OnNewLine}{%
    \let\thelstnumber\relax%
     \advance\c@lstnumber-\@ne\relax%
    }%
}

\newcommand*\Reactivatenumber[1]{%
  \lst@AddToHook{OnNewLine}{%
   \let\thelstnumber\origthelstnumber%
   \setcounter{lstnumber}{\numexpr#1-1\relax}%
   %\advance\c@lstnumber\@ne\relax%
  }%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
First listing:
\begin{lstlisting}[firstnumber=1]
var myFunc = function() {|\Suppressnumber|
    //my function does many great things
    //and it's only 10 lines long!|\Reactivatenumber{12}|
}

var oneMoreFunc = function() {
    return myFunc;
}
\end{lstlisting}
One more listing:
\begin{lstlisting}[firstnumber=18]
var something = "bla";
console.log(something);
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image: Result of my example]

Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your definition to

```
\newcommand*\Reactivatenumber[1]{%
  \setcounter{lstnumber}{\numexpr#1-1\relax}
  \lst@AddToHook{OnNewLine}{%
   \let\thelstnumber\origthelstnumber%
   \refstepcounter{lstnumber}
  }%
}
```

[image]

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{numbers=left,numberblanklines=false,escapeinside=||}
\let\origthelstnumber\thelstnumber
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\Suppressnumber{%
  \lst@AddToHook{OnNewLine}{%
    \let\thelstnumber\relax%
     \advance\c@lstnumber-\@ne\relax%
    }%
}

\newcommand*\Reactivatenumber[1]{%
  \setcounter{lstnumber}{\numexpr#1-1\relax}
  \lst@AddToHook{OnNewLine}{%
   \let\thelstnumber\origthelstnumber%
   \refstepcounter{lstnumber}
  }%
}


\makeatother

\begin{document}
First listing:
\begin{lstlisting}[firstnumber=1]
var myFunc = function() {|\Suppressnumber|
    //my function does many great things
    //and it's only 10 lines long!|\Reactivatenumber{12}|
}

var oneMoreFunc = function() {
    return myFunc;
}

}

var oneMoreFunc = function() {
    return myFunc;
}
\end{lstlisting}
One more listing:
\begin{lstlisting}[firstnumber=18]
var something = "bla";
console.log(something);

}

var oneMoreFunc = function() {
    return myFunc;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A small addition to to the previous also correct answer.
At the end of the line:

```
\refstepcounter{lstnumber}%
```

There should be a '%'. Omitting this will result in subsequent inline listings to be improperly formatted.

The reactivate command is then as follows:

```
\newcommand*\Reactivatenumber[1]{%
  \setcounter{lstnumber}{\numexpr#1-1\relax}
  \lst@AddToHook{OnNewLine}{%
   \let\thelstnumber\origthelstnumber%
   \refstepcounter{lstnumber}%
  }%
}
```