# Excessive space in lstinline after using Reactivatenumber

Tags: listings

I'm using the code presented by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/264373/39635) (which itself is based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/215752/39635)) to suppress line numbers on some lines in `lstlisting`. This works, but after I use it, the spacing in `lstinline` is messed up:

[image: messed up lstinline spacing]

This seems to be because of `|\Reactivatenumber{12}|`. Why is that and how do I fix it?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{numbers=left,escapeinside=||, basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize}

\let\origthelstnumber\thelstnumber
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\Suppressnumber{%
  \lst@AddToHook{OnNewLine}{%
    \let\thelstnumber\relax%
     \advance\c@lstnumber-\@ne\relax%
    }%
}

\newcommand*\Reactivatenumber[1]{%
  \setcounter{lstnumber}{\numexpr#1-1\relax}
  \lst@AddToHook{OnNewLine}{%
   \let\thelstnumber\origthelstnumber%
   \refstepcounter{lstnumber}
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
This looks fine: \lstinline!some-words-with-minus! more text\dots
\begin{lstlisting}[firstnumber=1]
var myFunc = function() {|\Suppressnumber|
    //my function does many great things
    //and it's only 10 lines long!|\Reactivatenumber{12}|
}
\end{lstlisting}

This looks awful: \lstinline!some-words-with-minus! some more text
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK found it: I needed to add a `%` after `\refstepcounter{lstnumber}`.

Complete snippet:

```
\let\origthelstnumber\thelstnumber
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\Suppressnumber{%
  \lst@AddToHook{OnNewLine}{%
    \let\thelstnumber\relax%
     \advance\c@lstnumber-\@ne\relax%
    }%
}

\newcommand*\Reactivatenumber[1]{%
  \setcounter{lstnumber}{\numexpr#1-1\relax}
  \lst@AddToHook{OnNewLine}{%
   \let\thelstnumber\origthelstnumber%
   \refstepcounter{lstnumber}%
  }%
}
\makeatother
```