# Skip line numbers and resume from specific number in Minted?

Tags: minted, code

This question has already been [asked for the package `listings`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215697/skip-line-numbers-and-resume-from-specific-number), but I am using `minted` and want to achieve the same thing.

My document looks as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}[breaklines=true,linenos]{javascript}
/* My Code: */

console.log("Hello");

console.log("World");
console.log("FooBar");

console.log("BarFoo");
console.log("FooFoo");

\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

This gives me the following output:

[image: Minted_LaTeX_skip_line_numbers]

However, I want to have the following result:

```
1  | /* My Code: */
...|
128| console.log("Hello");
...|
188| console.log("World");
189| console.log("FooBar");
...|
201| console.log("BarFoo");
202| console.log("FooFoo");
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\theFancyVerbLine{%
\ifnum\value{FancyVerbLine}=2 
  \setcounter{FancyVerbLine}{127}\ldots
\else\ifnum\value{FancyVerbLine}=129
  \setcounter{FancyVerbLine}{187}\ldots
\else\ifnum\value{FancyVerbLine}=190
  \setcounter{FancyVerbLine}{200}\ldots
\else
\arabic{FancyVerbLine}%
\fi
\fi
\fi
}
\begin{minted}[breaklines=true,linenos]{javascript}
/* My Code: */

console.log("Hello");

console.log("World");
console.log("FooBar");

console.log("BarFoo");
console.log("FooFoo");

\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works for perfectly, but now all of my other code snippets also have that numbering. How can I reset it or limit it to one specific `minted`?

Comment: @JohnDoe yes the definition of `\theFancyVerbLine` is local so you can do it inside any existing group (eg if this is in `figure` or just surround by `{ ..renewcommand...begin minted ...end minted ...}` so it is restored at the `}`

Comment: What an ugly hack. I love it :-)

Comment: @bp99 I believe you have a typo and you intended to write "brilliantly engineered solution"