# How can I add additional spacing between some lines in `minted`?

Tags: listings, minted, code, fancyvrb

I would like to add a little separation between some lines of code for readibility.
Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}[linenos]{python}
foo(1)
bar(1)
foofoo(1)
foobar(1)
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

The produced output of course looks like

```
1 foo(1)
2 bar(1)
3 foobar(1)
4 foobaz(1)
```

**What I would want to see is**

```
1 foo(1)
2 bar(1)

3 foobar(1)
4 foobaz(1)
```

(With not necessarily an entire line’s spacing between lines 2 and 3, but some extra space.)

---

I first tried to use the minted options `[escapeinside=]` and `\\[2ex]`, but it did nothing. I mean the `\\` was recognized as a TeX command, since it did not show in the output, but no `2ex` spacing was added.

I then stumbled upon David’s (brilliantly engineered ☺) answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380013), but that solution still increments the line counter on the next line.

```
\renewcommand\theFancyVerbLine{%
    \ifnum\value{FancyVerbLine}=3
        \setcounter{FancyVerbLine}3
    \else
        {\scriptsize\arabic{FancyVerbLine}}
    \fi
}
```

I cannot do `\setcounter{FancyVerbLine}2` as that would cause an infinite loop, setting each line number to `2` starting from the 3rd line and not printing anything.

Comment: I also experimented with adding a `\newif\ifthreeocunted\threecountedfalse` and then doing `\ifthreecounted\arabic{FancyVerbLine}\else\setcounter{FancyVerbLine}2\threecountedtrue` in the `\ifnum...` block, but something is still missing. Line numbers are only printed up to 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use an invisible rule with the appropriate depth.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\newcommand\spacer[1]{\rule[-#1]{0pt}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}[linenos,escapeinside=||]{python}
foo(1)
bar(1)|\spacer{3ex}|
foofoo(1)
foobar(1)
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is superb. Thanks. I think it’s useful to have a default parameter if used often `\newcommand*\spacer[1][3ex]{\rule[-#1]{0pt}{#1}}`

Comment: @bp99 Yes, that can be a good idea. For some reasons, `|\rule[3ex]{0pt}{3ex}|` doesn't work, but I'm not going to investigate.