# Custom numberstyle for lines that are \ref'ed in a listing environment

Tags: cross-referencing, listings

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{%
  basicstyle =\ttfamily,
  language = Python,
  keywordstyle = \bfseries,
  commentstyle = \itshape,
  numbers = left,
  numberstyle = \tiny\sffamily,
  escapechar = |,
  gobble = 2,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
  import numpy as np
  from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

  t = np.linspace(0, 1, 100) |\label{that-line}|
  plt.plot(t, t**2)
  plt.show() |\label{that-other-line}|
\end{lstlisting}

Please see line~\ref{that-line} and line~\ref{that-other-line}.

\end{document}
```

The current output is:

[image: listing-output]

I'd like the numbers corresponding to the lines that are `\ref`'ed (so lines 4 and 6 in my MWE) to have a specific style (e.g. typesetted inside a square or a circle, ideally arbitrary `tikz` code). For example:

[image: with-circles]

Comment: Try  `\def\REF#1{AAA-\ref{#1}}`. Change the AAA to what you need.

Comment: @yannisl Thanks but I meant the numbers in the listing.

Comment: Thanks Let me think about this. This is harder, what I do I format the label with circled numbers. Like you see in some computer books and leave the listing numbering alone.

Comment: Like this https://imgur.com/P5k2Yhd

Comment: @yannisl Unfortunately, no. That's not what I've been asked.

Comment: Maybe use zref to add a porporty to the label so that we know it is inside the lstlisting environment. Then parse all labels that belongs to the specific lstlisting environment and finally compate \lst@lineno with the lines corresponding to the selected labels.

Comment: I made a draft with a boolean and it is working but needs some cleanup to fix a bug. Will post a solution in the morning, if nobody else answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An adaptation of my answer at [How to add referrable numbered circle symbols to code listings?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/673824/how-to-add-referrable-numbered-circle-symbols-to-code-listings/673830):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{circledsteps}
\pgfkeys{/csteps/outer color=orange}

\lstset{%
  basicstyle =\ttfamily,
  language = Python,
  keywordstyle = \bfseries,
  commentstyle = \itshape,
  numbers = left,
  numberstyle = \tiny\sffamily,
  escapechar = |,
  gobble = 2,
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\CircleNext{%
  \lst@AddToHook{OnNewLine}{%
   \def\thelstnumber{\Circled{\arabic{lstnumber}}\hskip-2.1pt}}%
}
\def\circlabel#1{
  \lst@AddToHook{OnNewLine}{%
   \def\thelstnumber{\arabic{lstnumber}}}%
  \label{#1}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
  import numpy as np
  from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
  |\CircleNext|
  t = np.linspace(0, 1, 100) |\circlabel{that-line}|
  plt.plot(t, t**2)|\CircleNext|
  plt.show() |\circlabel{that-other-line}|
\end{lstlisting}

Please see line~\ref{that-line} and line~\ref{that-other-line}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Below a variant that doesn't need the `\CircleNext` commands. It works by writing an extra label consisting of the format `listing number-line number`. Instead of an `OnNewLine` hook for listings, now the command `\thelstnumber` (which prints the line number for every line) is modified to check if the label for the current listing and current line exists or not. If the label exists then the number is circled (at the next run).

Unfortunately `\thelstnumber` is also written to the .aux file as the label text which is read by `\ref`. To prevent circled numbers in the main text a solution is to temporarily redefine `\thelstnumber` to be just the number when writing the regular `\label`.

The rest of the code is bookkeeping to create and increment the listings counter that is used in the new label.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcounter{lstprefix}
\setcounter{lstprefix}{0}
\usepackage{listings}
\AddToHook{env/lstlisting/before}{\stepcounter{lstprefix}}

\usepackage{circledsteps}
\pgfkeys{/csteps/outer color=orange}

\lstset{%
  basicstyle =\ttfamily,
  language = Python,
  keywordstyle = \bfseries,
  commentstyle = \itshape,
  numbers = left,
  numberstyle = \tiny\sffamily,
  escapechar = |,
  gobble = 2,
}
\makeatletter
\def\thelstnumber{%
\ifcsname r@lst\thelstprefix-\arabic{lstnumber}\endcsname%
\Circled{\arabic{lstnumber}}\hskip-2.1pt%
\else%
\arabic{lstnumber}%
\fi%
}
\def\circlabel#1{
  {\def\thelstnumber{\arabic{lstnumber}}\label{#1}}%
  \label{lst\thelstprefix-\arabic{lstnumber}}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
  import numpy as np
  from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
  
  t = np.linspace(0, 1, 100) |\circlabel{that-line}|
  plt.plot(t, t**2)
  plt.show() |\circlabel{that-other-line}|
\end{lstlisting}

Please see line~\ref{that-line} and line~\ref{that-other-line}.

\begin{lstlisting}
  import numpy as np
  from matplotlib import pyplot as plt |\circlabel{import-line}|
  
  t = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
  plt.plot(t, t**2)
  plt.show()
\end{lstlisting}
See also line \ref{import-line}.
\end{document}
```

This creates the following .aux file:

```
\relax 
\newlabel{that-line}{{4}{1}}
\newlabel{lst1-4}{{\Circled {4}\hskip -2.1pt}{1}}
\newlabel{that-other-line}{{6}{1}}
\newlabel{lst1-6}{{\Circled {6}\hskip -2.1pt}{1}}
\newlabel{import-line}{{2}{1}}
\newlabel{lst2-2}{{\Circled {2}\hskip -2.1pt}{1}}
\gdef \@abspage@last{1}
```

Comment: Thanks (+1)! It works nicely. It would be even better if I did not have to add \CircleNext to the line before the label. But I understand it is quite tricky.

Comment: @cjorssen Once you are at the label the line number has already been generated, so then it's too late. Maybe you can leverage the information in the .aux file to circle the relevant lines on the second run, then `\CircleNext` may not be needed. If I have time I'll look into that.

Comment: @cjorssen I added a version without `\CircleNext`.

Comment: @Marijn Any idea how to make it work with hyperref?

Comment: Super nice! Thanks and accepted.

Comment: @cjorssen indeed as Yannis commented it does not work with `hyperref` at the moment, I'm not quite sure how that can be fixed but maybe I can take another look later.