# Skip line number in listing doesn't work

Tags: listings, line-numbering

I'm trying to skip some line numbers in my listing but it doesn't work. I followed this guide [Skip line numbers and resume from specific number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215697/skip-line-numbers-and-resume-from-specific-number) ... don't know why it's not working.

The new line number always shows in my border. Hope someone can help me.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\colorlet{punct}{red!60!black}
\definecolor{background}{HTML}{EEEEEE}
\definecolor{delim}{RGB}{20,105,176}
\colorlet{numb}{magenta!60!black}

\let\origthelstnumber\thelstnumber
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\Suppressnumber{%
  \lst@AddToHook{OnNewLine}{%
    \let\thelstnumber\relax%
     \advance\c@lstnumber-\@ne\relax%
    }%
}

\newcommand*\Reactivatenumber{%
  \lst@AddToHook{OnNewLine}{%
   \let\thelstnumber\origthelstnumber%
   \advance\c@lstnumber\@ne\relax}%
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=c++,basicstyle=\footnotesize\sffamily,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    frame={leftline,bottomline,rightline,topline},
    backgroundcolor={\color{background}},numbers=left,xleftmargin=15pt, firstnumber=195,caption={This is a test beginning with line 195 },label=lst:code,captionpos=b,escapeinside=||]
while (player->moveNext()) {
    StringName term = player->get();

    if (bla.exp) {
        bla.exp *= 2;
    } else {
        bla.exp = 1;
    }
    term++;
}|\Suppressnumber|

// ...
|\Reactivatenumber{214}|
// this is a very (SHOULD START AT 214)
// long
// comment

double etc = 0.6 * (x/y) - speedlimit;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

And it's always pushing the new line number inside the box like this:
[image]

Hope someone can help me :)

Comment: Your `\Reactivatenumber` command has no argument, but your using it with `{214}`, that's why the number 214 appears in the listing text

Comment: Oh .. yes i see.. what a horrible mistake thanks @ChristianHupfer 
It's working now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two logic errors in there:

- `|\Reactivatenumber{214}|` 
  is used as a macro with argument but it is not defined as such, so `214` is no argument but just a token that is left in the input stream, appearing as text in the listings.
- The other one is that the `lstnumber` counter is never set to `214` there, so this must be done with `\setcounter{lstnumber}{214}` or `\global\c@lstnumber=#1`, followed by a decrease by one then.

  ```
  \newcommand\Reactivatenumber[1]{%
    \global\c@lstnumber#1%
    \global\advance\c@lstnumber\m@ne\relax%
    \lst@AddToHook{OnNewLine}{%
    \let\thelstnumber\origthelstnumber%
    }%
  }
  ```

Here is the final code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\colorlet{punct}{red!60!black}
\definecolor{background}{HTML}{EEEEEE}
\definecolor{delim}{RGB}{20,105,176}
\colorlet{numb}{magenta!60!black}

\let\origthelstnumber\thelstnumber
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\Suppressnumber{%
  \lst@AddToHook{OnNewLine}{%
    \let\thelstnumber\relax%
%    \advance\c@lstnumber-\@ne\relax% Not really necessary
  }%
}

\newcommand\Reactivatenumber[1]{%
  \global\c@lstnumber#1%
  \global\advance\c@lstnumber\m@ne\relax%
  \lst@AddToHook{OnNewLine}{%
  \let\thelstnumber\origthelstnumber%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=c++,basicstyle=\footnotesize\sffamily,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    frame={leftline,bottomline,rightline,topline},
    backgroundcolor={\color{background}},numbers=left,xleftmargin=15pt, firstnumber=195,caption={This is a test beginning with line 195 },label=lst:code,captionpos=b,escapeinside=||]
while (player->moveNext()) {
    StringName term = player->get();

    if (bla.exp) {
        bla.exp *= 2;
    } else {
        bla.exp = 1;
    }
    term++;
}|\Suppressnumber|
// ...
|\Reactivatenumber{214}|
// this is a very (SHOULD START AT 214)
// long
// comment

double etc = 0.6 * (x/y) - speedlimit;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]