# Listings: skip line number ONLY where command is defined

Tags: listings, line-numbering

I have looked at the following:

1. [Suppress line numbering for empty lines in listings package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33999/suppress-line-numbering-for-empty-lines-in-listings-package)
2. [Suppress line numbering for specific lines in listings package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34094/suppress-line-numbering-for-specific-lines-in-listings-package)

However, the solution given in the latter thread only skips the line *after* the `|\Suppressnumber|` command is given, and likewise, only resumes numbering *after* the `|\Reactivatenumber|` command is given. In other words, this gives a range of skipped numbers.

What I'd like is:

1. the line number to be suppressed for empty lines (and the counter *not* incremented: this problem is solved in the first post above);
2. for specified lines *only*, not a range, to have their line numbers suppressed *without* incrementing the counter.

Using some *very* contrived C, for instance, this is what I would like to have:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
   int main () { |\Suppressnumber|
1      printf("hello\n");
2       while (1) {
3            ;
4            if (0) {
5                ;
             } else {   |\Suppressnumber|
6                  int b;
7                  scanf("%d", &b);
             }  |\Suppressnumber|
        }    |\Suppressnumber|
    }   |\Suppressnumber|           
\end{lstlisting}
```

I have experimented with most of the relevant hooks in `listings`, including `EveryLine`, `EOL`, `EveryPar`, `InitVarsBOL` and `InitVarsEOL`, and I can't think of a way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem of the second solution, as you describe it, is that when you use `|\Suppressnumber|` it suppresses the **NEXT** line. This would not be a problem: simply place the `|\Suppressnumber|` on the line *previous* to the one you wish to suppress, then the `|\Reactivatenumber|` on the line *itself*

Using this method you'd *almost* get the required output since you need the first line to be suppressed. If you do as the previous paragraph suggests you'll have an empty first line numbered one. Then the rest of the output would be numbered as you desire - only off by one.

The solution would be to use [the solution suggested here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/203229/90297) to number the first line with 0 and remove it.

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{numbers=left,numberblanklines=false,firstnumber=0,escapeinside=||}
\let\origthelstnumber\thelstnumber
\makeatletter
\def\lst@PlaceNumber{\ifnum\value{lstnumber}=0\else
  \llap{\normalfont\lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber}\kern\lst@numbersep}\fi}
\newcommand*\Suppressnumber{%
  \lst@AddToHook{OnNewLine}{%
    \let\thelstnumber\relax%
     \advance\c@lstnumber-\@ne\relax%
    }%
}

\newcommand*\Reactivatenumber{%
  \lst@AddToHook{OnNewLine}{%
   \let\thelstnumber\origthelstnumber%
   \advance\c@lstnumber\@ne\relax}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
|\Suppressnumber|
   int main () { |\Reactivatenumber|
      printf("hello\n"); 
       while (1) { 
            ;
            if (0) 
                ;{|\Suppressnumber|
             } else {   |\Reactivatenumber|
                  int b;
                  scanf("%d", &b);|\Suppressnumber|
             }  
        }    
    }  
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

And the output

[image]